# Common collector-emitter, feedback loop

Tags: amplifier, bjt, impedance

My goal is understanding voltage and input impedance difference between calculation and spice simulation in circuit like below:

[image: Circuit]

Predicted: k=U_Rc/25mV=6V/25mV=*240 V/V*, R_input=(25mV/Ib || 1k)*B || 82k=109k || 82k=*47k*, hfe=B=420 A/A

Simulated: k=*113 V/V*, R_input=*13k*

Whats more, deleting R7 resistor and editing R5/R6 divider for same current (Ic_Q1=30mA) results in dropping (to circa 70%) voltage gain and increasing (two times) input resistance.

Comment: When you "delete" R7, where do you connect the base of Q1 ?

Comment: The spice simulation *IS* a calculation and a better calculation than anyone here would bother doing by hand. So, I'm unsure about the point of your question.

Comment: Are you aware about negative feedback and its influence on gain and input impedance?

Comment: Deleting R7: Q2 emitter just just shorted with Q1 base, nothing more or less.

Comment: It is just academic project where I have to design such amplifier and calculate parameters. 
There are tones of bjt models and I have no idea which is correct and represents BC547 correctly.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/common-emitter-o-p-set-by-feedback-resistor/366891#366891